# What exactly do I have to escape inside a `script` element?

Tags: javascript, html, escaping

What parts of JavaScript code do I have to escape inside a `script` element in a HTML page? Is `<>&` enough or too much?

**[EDIT]** This is related to this bug: http://code.google.com/p/rendersnake/issues/detail?id=15#c6 comment #6

Comment: Of course, if you have a single `script` element that refers to an external, cacheable file (preferably one you've run through a minifier/packer/compressor), you don't have to worry about this at all... ;-)

Comment: The answer seems to vary between HTML < 5, XHTML, and HTML 5.  The HTML5 answer is interesting, in terms of the way the content restrictions are phrased: http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#restrictions-for-contents-of-script-elements

Comment: There are also a **lot** of myths and misconceptions about parsing behaviours and escaping especially, and I believe that this is mostly due to the very widespread act of people sending XHTML as `text/html`, thus invoking the HTML parser. While doing so isn't 'wrong' according to the W3C, it damn well should be, as it's a complete can of worms.

Comment: @Ray. No, Delan's answer is correct. HTML5 and earlier versions are not, in practice, different. Only the mime type changes things.

Comment: Thanks, Alochi, perhaps I misread HTML5's explicit treatment of HTML comments within the script element?  I did not see a similar treatment in the HTML4 spec (http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/scripts.html#h-18.2.1) but I may have missed it.  I do like Delan's answer, too, with the `>` clarification in the comments as the CDATA/PCDATA is absolutely key.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In HTML (and XHTML if you're an [evil person](http://hixie.ch/advocacy/xhtml) that sends your XHTML pages as `text/html`), `script` tags are `#CDATA`, and therefore, the only thing that you shouldn't have in the content is `</script>`, as that is all that the parser looks for to signal the end of the tag. Don't escape anything; just make sure you don't have `</script>` in the tag content. For example, if you have a string with a closing script tag, split it up:

```
var a = '</scr' + 'ipt>';
```

In XHTML, sent as `application/xhtml+xml`, `script` tags are `#PCDATA`, and therefore, escaping `<` and `&` is necessary, unless you can use a `<![CDATA[ ... ]]>` block to change to `#CDATA` parsing mode, but in that case, remember that you can't have `]]>` in your tag content.

Comment: Why `>`?  Aren't `<` and `&` all that must be escaped in XML?

Comment: Just checked http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/REC-xml-20001006#syntax -- You only need to escape `>` as `&gt;` when it would otherwise terminate a CDATA section with `]]>`.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, the only thing I escape is the `/` in closing tags.  Thus:

```
var msg = "<p>Do you <em>really<\/em> think so, Miss Worthington?<\/p>";
```

For the rest, I rely on commenting out the entire thing:

```
<script>
<!--
var msg = "<p>Do you <em>really<\/em> think so, Miss Worthington?<\/p>";
-->
</script>
```

The comment takes care of the HTML opening tags.

Comment: You don't actually need to do either of those, due to the parsing behaviour of HTML.

Comment: Actually, Javascript interpreter turns `\/` into `/` so generally you don't need to escape slash in closing tags. The only exception is to turn `</script>` into `<\/script>` because `</script>` would prematurely close your `<script>` element which holds the javascript.

Comment: Also, remember that if your document is XHTML, sent with the proper MIME type, your example's script tag will be effectively empty, as the comment will be parsed as one.

Comment: Meh.  The validator complains when it finds unescaped closing tags in the JS.  Really, though, the best way is to avoid inline JS entirely. It's easier to cache and minify external files anyway.

Comment: @Will Martin: Correct but since the HTML spec allows to inline JS, a HTML generator should do a decent job about it, don't you think? :-)

Answer (score -2):

Escaped <, > and & does not work with many browsers. It is good an enough if you put everything inside a CDATA section. Please note that the CDATA section itself will have to be in a JavaScript comment, for this to work with all browsers.

```
<script>
// <![CDATA[
 script here
// ]]>
</script>
```

Comment: And like @Delan pointed out, you still cannot have the string </script> within a script tag. It may fail in some browsers.

Comment: This is wrong! In HTML, `script` is `#CDATA` already. The only place where `script` is `#PCDATA` is in XHTML, sent with the proper XHTML MIME type.

Comment: So this will work for both XHTML and HTML. I agree it is superfluous for HTML (as it is already CDATA, and will be treated as text, and JavaScript ignores it due to it being in a comment), and increases the byte count. A little something left over in me due to all the time spent on XHTML :)