# </script> tag in wrong place

Tags: javascript, html, web, tags

I don't have any idea why my web browsers returns "SyntaxError: Unexpected EOF" errors on my website. I didn't make any changes but something had to change because yesterday same site works fine.

Here is my source code (directly from FTP server):

```html
<script type="">

 $(function(){

       $("body").append("<div class='tooltip2_showv' id='tooltip2_show'></div>");
        $('a.button.notactive').mousemove(function(e){

     $('#tooltip2_show').html( $('.popup',$(this)).html());
         $('#tooltip2_show').show();
              $('#tooltip2_show').css({'top': e.pageY + 5, left: e.pageX + 5,'position': 'absolute'});
                
          }).mouseout(function(){
           $('#tooltip2_show').hide();
          });
      });

</script>
```

It looks fine but check the same code from web browser (Web Inspector):

```html
<script type="">

 $(function(){

       $("body").append("<div class='tooltip2_showv' id='tooltip2_show'></script></div>");
        $('a.button.notactive').mousemove(function(e){

     $('#tooltip2_show').html( $('.popup',$(this)).html());
         $('#tooltip2_show').show();
              $('#tooltip2_show').css({'top': e.pageY + 5, left: e.pageX + 5,'position': 'absolute'});
                
          }).mouseout(function(){
           $('#tooltip2_show').hide();
          });
      });
```

End of script tag is in WRONG place! Have you any idea why?
It's not the only wrong placed "end of script" tag.

Happy Easter ;)

Comment: just use <script> not <script type="">

Comment: @Zet Maybe you have an extension that messes with scripts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't have things like `</div>` inside a script. To the parser, that means the script has ended. So it includes an automatic `</script>` because that's the proper thing to do!

Solution: don't put `</div>` in your script. Write `<\/div>`.

Oh, and remove the `type=""`, which is wrong.

Comment: Huh, how are you creating divs inside a script? His code is fine, but he included a script tag which ended the execution.You don't have to escape anything because everything is quoted...

Comment: @Mikey If you read the question again, the OP didn't add the `</script>` himself; he discovered that the `</script>` turned up unexpectedly in the Web Inspector. And it wouldn't matter if the text was inside quotes (or inside a comment, for that matter).

Comment: Ah ok, I see now. But you still don't have to escape the forward slash :). Maybe an extension messing with scripts?

Comment: @Mikey [This W3C page](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/types.html#h-6.2) says __The first occurrence of the character sequence "</" (end-tag open delimiter) is treated as terminating the end of the element's content.__ That is, the end of the script

Comment: Yes, but OP is just appending a string to the DOM that is being interpreted by the browser as HTML. How do you explain my fiddle working, no errors in the console and the `div` is appended. It is already escaped you don't have to worry about it anymore.

Comment: It is not escaped! Well, yes, in your fiddle, because the fiddle has put a `<![CDATA[` block around it. This is not so in the OP's code.

Comment: Yay, it works! Thank you a lot. Have you any idea why yesterday same code works? Maybe some php or some module has been updated?

Comment: @ZetKonrad Probably, yes. No idea what, but in these cases, it's always best to program defensively.

Comment: @MrLister No you don't need to escape the closing tags of normal elements only script tags, see this post and the answers with comments http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6908866/what-exactly-do-i-have-to-escape-inside-a-script-element, seriously it is unnecessary.

Comment: @Mikey It did solve the OP's problem though. Seriously.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**: your code works fine as long as you take out the `</script>` out of your append method http://jsfiddle.net/byadd1m3/. What I like better is to create the element and store that in variable. Define a variable with the new div and append the variable later to the body. Like this:

```
 $(function () {
     var newDiv = "<div class='tooltip2_showv' id='tooltip2_show'></div>";
     $("body").append(newDiv);
     $('a.button.notactive').mousemove(function (e) {
         $('#tooltip2_show').html($('.popup', $(this)).html());
         $('#tooltip2_show').show();
         $('#tooltip2_show').css({
             'top': e.pageY + 5,
             left: e.pageX + 5,
             'position': 'absolute'
         });

     }).mouseout(function () {
         $('#tooltip2_show').hide();
     });
 });
```

Why your code doesn't work:

```
    $("body").append("<div class='tooltip2_showv' id='tooltip2_show'>
</script></div>");//What is script doing here?
```