# How to include inline JS files with PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, html

Normally that is how one includes JS files in HTML:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="myFile.js" ></script>
```

But I want to write the JS file inline the HTML, using PHP; but still having the possibility of having my neat JS file, that can be chached, debugged and minified.

How can I do something like this?

```
<script>
<?php include 'myFile.js';?>
</script>
```

In other words,  how to include a JS file in HTML on the server-side. That may get a lot of advantages because it is transparent to the browser.

Comment: what is the problem with `<script type="text/javascript" src="myFile.js" ></script>`  ??

Comment: You should stick with the script include as that will allow your browser to handle caching, and therefore decrease load times.  What you are suggesting is counter-intuitive and flies against the whole point of script includes.  Maybe if you have a specific problem that your suggestion would address then you should explain that problem instead, as this is not the way to fix something.

Comment: (just if you really need it) <?= file_get_contents('myFile.js') ?>

Comment: @DivyeshSavaliya, in this way, the JS file is included in HTML in the server-side. That may bring a lot of advantages because it is transparent to the browser.

Comment: @Archer, don't forget that with this way the JS file is included in HTML in the server-side, which makes it a lot different.

Comment: That is exactly why it's wrong.  Everything that can be cached should be cached separately - not together.  Why do you think that is better?

Comment: "It is transparent to the browser"...?! Well, it also means the browser needs to download the same script every single time; whereas it could be caching an external file...

Comment: @Archer; In this case, for the index.php, if the file is small and because it is loaded just once, and if the JS is not so big, I read that the initial loading time of the HTML gets on average smaller.

Comment: @deceze, it is for the index.php, so It will be loaded just once and the JS is not that big. There are cases where putting thigs inline is more effective.

Comment: No there is not.  You're not understanding something if you think this is better.  Using a script include means that you can change the php file (as will most likely happen every single load) and the JS file will never need to be downloaded again, unless it changes.  What you are proposing will most likely download it every single time.

Comment: @Archer Though if the code *is* very small (I'd say a few dozen lines max), and initial download speed is the ultimate goal, this can very well be a valid thing to do. Reducing one HTTP request can be somewhat more significant than a few added bytes.

Comment: @Archer, in the index.php, since you just load it once (unless you refresh the page), there are cases where the initial page loading time is faster if you inline the script. And the search engines rankings are very sensible to the initial page loading time. And yes, we reduce one HTTP request.

Comment: Okay, well I've given you solid advice, but it's your call to take it or leave it.   There's no point continuing to repeat the same things to each other.  Good luck :)

Comment: @Archer, thank you; and please do not downgrade my question :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I do something like this?
>
> ```
> <script>
> <?php include 'myFile.js';?>
> </script>
> ```

Exactly that code would work, yes. Though it would try to interpret the file as PHP code, and if anything looked like `<?php .. ?>` inside that file you may see weird side effects. If you want to include the file uninterpreted, simply do:

```
<script><?php echo file_get_contents('myFile.js'); ?></script>
```

Be aware of possibly having to escape `"</script>"` now, should that appear in your included file; see https://stackoverflow.com/a/6908901/476.

Answer (score -3):

YOu need to make custom function or use :

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript" src="myFile.js" ></script>';

Or 

function add_js($filename){
return '<script type="text/javascript" src="'.$filename.'" ></script>';
}
echo add_js('myFile.js');
```

Comment: He wants the JS included in the php output.  This just allows for adding a script include which he already has.